# Как в консоли Ububtu "свернуть" Java-приложение, не останавливая его работу?

Tags: linux

Запускаю jar-файл на VPS. Он представляет собой простенький сервер, поэтому надо, чтобы он работал постоянно. Но если закрываю консоль и разрываю соединение с VPS, процесс прекращается.

Как мне добиться того, чтобы, запустившись на VPS, этот сервер продолжал бы работать и после того, как я разорву SSH-соединение с VPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Tuhlom](/users/1743/tuhlom), используйте screen или tmux, это так называемые мултиплексоры, которые способны хранить сеанс между подключениями пользователя.

Comment: Другими словами эти штуки позволяют переподключиться к терминалу, например, после обрыва связи или на следующий день - после сна, и продолжить работу как будто не отключались. Консоль продолжает работать (пока вы явно ее не закроете), как и программы, запущенные в ней. Как раз то, что вам нужно. Штука, просто незаменимая при работе в удаленной консоли!зы screen скорее всего у вас уже установлен

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз только что у меня всё получилось с помощью screen. И правда - отличнейшая вещь! Именно то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0):

самый простой вариант запуска приложения в фоне:

nohup java -jar myapplication.jar > log.txt 2> errors.txt < /dev/null & <- обязательно.

Comment: А как выводить его на передний план, а потом скрывать?Хотелось бы по необходимости читать сообщения сервера в реальном времени

Comment: все сообщения серверного приложения должны выводится в лог файл. используй например log4j.

Comment: Кажется, то, что сервер запущен в фоновом режиме, не мешает ему выводить ответы в консоль. Сейчас разберусь.Спасибо вам, уже не в первый раз меня выручаете!

Comment: если вы отключитесь от консоли вы не сможете потом когда подключитесь посмотреть что происходило на сервере.

Comment: можно попробовать писать лог так java -jar имя файла.jar >/path/to/some.log 2>&1

Comment: Это вы советуете мне логи использовать? Конечно, я прикручу их чуть попозже.Пока что у меня другая проблема: как только я отключаюсь от консоли, мой java-сервер вообще перестаёт работать... Запуск в фоновом режиме не помог.

Comment: покажите строку которую вы выполняете на сервере для запуска программы.

Comment: java -jar server.jar &Спасибо за то, что показали такой простой способ логгирования, обязательно возьму его на вооружение.